# How can I do a one to many Search in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, one-to-many, where-clause

Given the following

Tables:

```
Names
Id int
Name varchar

Properties
Id int
NameId varchar
PropertyValue int
```

Sample Data:

```
Names             Properties
Id  Name         Id    NameId     PropertyValue
1   Sam          1       1              1
2   Bam          2       1              2
3   Ram          3       2              1
```

I want to search through the properties table where NameId = 1
AND both criterias PropertyValue = 1 AND PropertyValue = 2 are applied

What I did was

```
SELECT dbo.Names.Id, dbo.Names.Name, dbo.PropertyValue
FROM dbo.Names
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Properties on dbo.Names.Id = dbo.Properties.NameId
WHERE dbo.Names.Id = 1
AND dbo.Properties.PropertyValue IN (1,2)
```

The IN does an OR, what I need is an AND, how can I achieve so ?

**EDIT:**

What I want is that when both criterias are met, to return two different rows even if it has duplicated data and when one of the two criterias is NOT met, not to return anything

Comment: I think I don't understand you right, you want Property value to be 1 and 2, how is that possible? It can't be both it's eaither 1 or 2, if you put AND it will never find match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to operate on a set of rows for each user. Basically, you want a user that has rows with both values. Try this:

```
select * from properties p1
join names n on p1.nameId = n.id
where exists (
  select 1 from properties p2
  where p1.nameId = p2.nameId and p2.propertyValue in (1, 2)
  group by p2.nameId
  having count(distinct p2.propertyValue) = 2
)
```

Another option (based on Francis') would be:

```
select * from properties
join names n on p1.nameId = n.id
where nameId in (
  select nameId from properties
  where propertyValue in (1, 2)
  group by nameId
  having count(distinct propertyValue) = 2
)
```

But I'm not sure which one will be faster.

Comment: having count(distinct propertyValue) = 2
2 is the count of what exactly ? count of elements in the set inside IN ?

Comment: The count of different propertyValue. The problem with count(*) is that if a user has two properties with propertyValue = 1 then that will match with Francis solution. However, that is not what you're looking for. So, it has to match distinctly: when two properties with value 1 are matched the distinct counts them as 1 and they don't match the condition on the having clause. Check this [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ba14/1) and remove the distinct. Results will not be accurate.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM NAMES
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT NAMEID FROM PROPERTIES 
  WHERE PROPERTYVALUE = 1 OR 
    PROPERTYVALUE = 2
  GROUP BY NAMEID
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Fiddle if you want to test it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23365/2

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you want, because it's not entirely clear(imho).

```
SELECT n.Id, n.Name, p.PropertyValue
FROM dbo.Names n
INNER JOIN dbo.Properties p on n.Id = p.NameId 
WHERE n.ID = 1
AND EXISTS(
    SELECT null FROM Properties p2
    WHERE p2.NameId=ID AND p2.PropertyValue=1
)
AND EXISTS(
    SELECT null FROM Properties p2
    WHERE p2.NameId=ID AND p2.PropertyValue=2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dbo.Names.Id, dbo.Names.Name, dbo.PropertyValue
FROM dbo.Names
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Properties on dbo.Names.Id = dbo.Properties.NameId
WHERE dbo.Names.Id = 1
AND dbo.Properties.PropertyValue=1
UNION
SELECT dbo.Names.Id, dbo.Names.Name, dbo.PropertyValue
FROM dbo.Names
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Properties on dbo.Names.Id = dbo.Properties.NameId
WHERE dbo.Names.Id = 1
AND dbo.Properties.PropertyValue=2
```